# Using same containers with multiple project on local host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

#### Problem

A have few projects on my computer, that all are developed.

I started working with docker few month ago and I share some config between projects.

I have clear container list each time. Why? Because usually my process need to look like:

1. Delete all containers `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`
2. Delete all images - `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`
3. run `docker-compose up -d`

The problem is everywhere, I have defined composer (like in config below). When I switch, but don't delete images/containers, then i have, that `composer/composer` container exist and don't start.

Of course, I use more services like that, but this is simples one.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.1.3-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
  composer:
    image: composer/composer
    volumes_from:
      - php
    working_dir: /app
```

#### My env

- Mac OSX 10.11.6
- Docker for mac: 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)

#### Till now

- searched texts like : `Docker multi use of containers` / `docker multi projects on local with same container`
- read some blog with configuration, but didn't get hint.

#### Summary

As the topic is to wide, to many pages. 
Maybe I ommited something in understand of concept or config.

Would be nice to get some explanation and hints for good manage `docker-compose.yml` files like that and what was wrong in my process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you're using `docker-compose` to bring the containers up but relying on `docker rm`/`docker rmi` to take them down. Try doing everything with Docker Compose. Bring services up:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Take services down but let volumes persist:

```
docker-compose down
```

Take services down and destroy volumes:

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

For the compose file you posted, you shouldn't generally need to use `docker rm`/`docker rmi`.

Comment: maybe the problem is that, use this config in few places. Then let down, but with volumes persist and when i run `docker-compose up -d` in other place, the this cause crash to build this. Will test this out and let you know about that.